# Are Functions Smooth Sections?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, vector-bundles, smooth-functions

In differential geometry we often identify $\Omega^0(M)$ with the smooth functions on
a smooth manifold $M$. But for every $i>0$ we know that:
$$\Omega^i(M)=\Gamma(\Lambda^i(T^*M))$$
I imagine with $i=0$ then $\Lambda^i(T^*M)$ would be the trivial line bundle since constant functions exist on $M$. So can we think about functions as smooth sections of this trivial line bundle? If this is true, does that mean for every smooth function $f$ there is a projection such that:
$$\pi\circ f=\text{Id}_M$$
If so, it would be very helpful to a problem I am currently working on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok never mind, this is easy. Let $M\times \mathbb{R}$ be the trivial line bundle, then for any smooth function $f$ on $M$, we can easily obtain a map:
$$\begin{align}
M&\longrightarrow M\times\mathbb{R}\\
p&\longmapsto (p,f(p))
\end{align}$$
The projection onto $M$ denoted by $\pi_M$ then satisfies the above requirement.